# How to resize a children shape from a pshape in Processing

Tags: java, processing, shapes

I am currently building an app using Processing.
I have a shape in which I was able to select its sub elements and manipulate its color and stroke... but I am not being able to resize every single element of the file. 
Basically, what I want is to resize the whole thing like in:

```
shape(shape, mouseX, mouseY, 600, 600);//parameters: shape, x-coor, y-coor, new width, new height;
```

and, to change the color of each element (just like the line above).
The code:

```
PShape shape;
int noOfChilds;
/***************************************************************************/
void setup() 
{
  size(1000, 600);
  shape = loadShape("a.svg");
  noOfChilds = shape.getChildCount();
  print(noOfChilds);
  shapeMode(CENTER);
} 
/***************************************************************************/
void draw() 
{
  background(100);
  shape.enableStyle();
  stroke(255);
  shape(shape, mouseX, mouseY, 600, 600);
  //
  shape.disableStyle();
  for(int i = 0; i < noOfChilds; i++)
  {
    pushMatrix();
    translate(300, 300);
    PShape ps = shape.getChild(i);
    fill(random(255),random(255),random(255));
    shape(ps, 0, 0);//shape(ps, 0, 0, anyValue, anyValue); seems to fail :'(
    popMatrix();
  }
}
/***************************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `PShape#scale()` function to scale individual `PShape` instances.

From [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/PShape_scale_.html):

> ```
> PShape s;
>
> void setup() {
>   s = loadShape("bot.svg");
> }
>
> void draw() {
>   background(204);
>   shape(s);
> }
>
> void mousePressed() {
>   // Shrink the shape 90% each time the mouse is pressed
>   s.scale(0.9);  
> }
> ```
>
> Increases or decreases the size of a shape by expanding and
>   contracting vertices. Shapes always scale from the relative origin of
>   their bounding box. Scale values are specified as decimal percentages.
>   For example, the method call scale(2.0) increases the dimension of a
>   shape by 200%. Subsequent calls to the method multiply the effect. For
>   example, calling scale(2.0) and then scale(1.5) is the same as
>   scale(3.0). This transformation is applied directly to the shape; it's
>   not refreshed each time draw() is run.

You could also use the more general `scale()` function. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/scale_.html).

Note that you might also have to adjust where you draw your shapes, potentially using the `translate()` function.

Comment: Thanks again, Kevin :)